# Azure SQL | PowerShell ISE vs PowerShell CLI - attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, connection, command-line-interface

I have a really frustrating situation here. There is a PowerShell script that logs into the Azure SQL, queries table, and saves results into the .csv file. Connection string looks like this:

```
$DatabaseUrl = "mycompany-***-***-dev-use4-01.database.windows.net"
$DatabaseName = "MyDataBase"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$DatabaseUrl;Initial Catalog=$DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=20"
$conn.AccessToken = $token
$conn.Open
```

On `$conn.Open` line the script throws this error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An
attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Now, the frustration comes when this script works perfectly fine in PowerShell ISE, but not in PowerShell CLI (command line). I have searched millions of posts probably by now, still not finding any solution. I tried to run CLI as an administrator, tried to `Import-Module -SQLServer -Scope CurrentUser` and others. Honestly, I have absolutely no idea why the script would work in ISE but not in CLI. Are those 2 different environments/scripting languages? Thank you for all your help

Comment: Are CLI and ISE running different versions of powershell? Try $PSVersionTable

Comment: Have you added the correct client ip to firewall rules? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart